Lagrange Multipliers in ADM formalism
I'm following this lecture notes (https://javierrubioblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/adm1.pdf) on ADM formalism. After getting action as (see Eq.(5.41))
$$
S=\int\mathrm{d}^4xN\sqrt{\gamma}\left[\frac{1}{2\kappa^2}\left(^{(3)}R+K_{ij}K^{ij}-K^2\right)+\frac12[(\Pi_\phi)^2-\partial^i\phi\partial_i\phi]-V(\phi)\right]\tag{5.41}
$$
it says that due to the missing of (time) derivatives of $N$ and $N^i$, these 2 variables can be considered to be Lagrange multipliers. I don't understand what does this mean, since that in
$$(\Pi_\phi)^2=\dfrac{1}{N^2}\left(\dot{\phi}-N^i\partial_i\phi\right)^2\tag{5.40}$$
both $N$ and $N^i$ show up, which seems to be a little different from the case in method of Lagrange multipliers I've known (For example $$L(x,y,\lambda_1,\lambda_2)=f(x,y)+\lambda_1g(x,y)+\lambda_2h(x,y),$$ and there is no term like $\lambda_1\lambda_2\varphi(x,y)$). So I don't understand how to get Eq.(5.43) and Eq.(5.44).
I'm also looking at appendix C of (https://arxiv.org/abs/0907.5424), getting the same problem on deriving Eq.(A.146) and Eq.(A.147) from Eq.(A.143).
Could you please show me how to do this kind of calculation with some details?


On one hand in the Lagrangian formalism, the lapse and shift functions $(N,N_i)$ are given in terms of the $g_{0\mu}$-components, and vice-versa, cf. eq. (5.10). $(N,N_i)$ may appear non-linearly in the Lagrangian density. They are auxiliary variables, since their time-derivatives do not appear in the Lagrangian density.

On the other hand in the Hamiltonian formalism, the canonical momenta $(\pi_0,\pi^i)$ for $(N,N_i)$ vanish due to primary constraints. $(N,N_i)$ appear linearly in the Hamiltonian Lagrangian density, and are therefore Lagrange multipliers, in fact for the secondary constraints, aka. 1 Hamiltonian + 3 momentum constraints, cf. e.g. my Phys.SE answer here.



The idea of the Hamiltonian formalism to express everything in terms of the fields $\phi$ and momenta $\Pi$ and use those as your fundamental variables. Once you do that, the Hamiltonian has the schematic form
$$
\mathcal{H} = N C(\phi, \Pi_\phi, h_{ij}, \pi_{ij}) + N_i C^i(\phi, \Pi_\phi, h_{ij}, \pi_{ij})
$$
where $h_{ij}$ and $\pi_{ij}$ are the spatial metric and its momentum respectively, and where the constraints $C$ and $C_i$ do not depend on $N$ and $N_i$. (Again, remember we are thinking of $\Pi_\phi$ as a fundamental variable here, so you should't rewrite it in terms of $\partial \phi$).
In this form, it's clear that $N$ and $N_i$ are Lagrange multipliers, enforcing the (first-class) constraints $C=C^i=0$.
